# Repeat macro after UserForm Input

Tags: vba, excel, userform, select-case

The macro ,upon opening the workbook, will look to see if cell "C27" contains any of the following Text: Location1, Location2, Location3, or Location4. If they do then it will continue to save 2 copy files of the template by those locations. If not then it will open a UserForm To select the correct location from a ComboBox.

How could i reset the check after the UserForm is closed, I tried Call Auto_Open after the Unload me but it didnt work.

Macro

```
 Sub Auto_Open()

With Range("B30")
.Value = Time
.NumberFormat = "h-mm-ss AM/PM"
End With

Dim FileName    As String
Dim FilePath    As String
Dim FileDate    As String

Select Case Range("C27").Value

    Case "Location1", "Location2", "Location3", "Location4"

        FilePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test"
        FileName = Sheets("Data").Range("C27").Text

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName

        Dim FileCopyName    As String
        Dim FileCopyPath    As String
        Dim FileTime        As String

        FilePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Backup"
        FileName = Sheets("Data").Range("C27").Text
        FileTime = Sheets("Data").Range("B30").Text

        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName & Space(1) & FileTime & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

        MsgBox "File was saved! Ready for Next Test, Please Exit."


    Case Else

        MsgBox "File was not saved, Please Insert The Correct Testing Location"

        UserForm.Show

    Exit Sub

End Select

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

UserForm

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  'Empty TestLocation Box
   TestLocation.Clear

  'Fill TestLocation Box
  With TestLocation
  .AddItem "Location1"
  .AddItem "Location2"
  .AddItem "Location3"
  .AddItem "Location4"
  End With

End Sub
```

'---------------------

```
Private Sub Insert_Click()

Sheets("Data").Activate

Range("C27").Value = TestLocation.Value

End Sub
```

'--------------------

```
Private Sub CloseBox_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("B27")` from what worksheet?

Comment: I meant to change that to C27, It doesn't matter I fixed It and it still does the same thing. Its weird cause if i change it using the UserForm it works but not if i open the workbook with the correct Location there it doesn't.

Comment: ohhhh I see what your saying now, hang on let me clarify that to the macro

Comment: Simple Typo, Location1 was in the case statement twice, leaving out location3... Which I was testing...

My second Question is still unanswered.

Comment: OK, try `Select Case Sheets("Data").Range("C27").Value` since that is the worksheet you `.Activate` to store the value.

Comment: I fixed it, It was because i wasn't telling it to look for location3 in the code, Because i had a typo (loaction1 twice) and because i was using location3 as the testing location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the following code for the insert button:

```
Private Sub Insert_Click()

   Sheets("Data").Range("C27").Value = TestLocation.Value
   Auto_Open
End Sub
```

The code will work (tested it), as long as you have the Auto_Open code in a module.

If you put the Auto_Open sub in the ThisWorkbook then move it to the module.

Then use the following code in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Auto_Open
End Sub
```

Also:

```
Case "Location1", "Location2", "Location1", "Location4"
```

Should be:

```
Case "Location1", "Location2", "Location3", "Location4"
```

Comment: Thanks! that works perfectly. And yeah I had a coworker go over it and he found it. Its nice to have a second pair of eyes.

Comment: Glad to have been of help :)